# Navbar modify border / background color on dropdown-menu item on click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I don't understand why I have a blue border when I click on the Item "My account" of a navbar item which opens a dropdown-menu:

[image]

So I tried to put all in red with `!important` like this but with no success:

```
nav a.nav-account.active {
   color: red !important;
   background: red !important;
   border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5o06orcg/1/

It's like it's not `.active` I have to edit. How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make !important border color for selector `nav a.nav-account`:

```
nav a.nav-account {
    color: white !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:13px;
    line-height:10px !important;
    border: 2px solid white !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a1vv9hvf/

Comment: Ok, I understand but I want to change the color (border, background and font) when we click on it.

Comment: WHat did YOU ask about in your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't been enough specific in the question

Comment: When menu is collapsed you need stylize `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a`. When menu axpanded, you need define styles for `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a`

Comment: Like that? http://jsfiddle.net/0gtyru6o/ The item border does not switch to red when we click on "My account".

Comment: Hah!!! I didn't catch a typo in your styles! You wrote `nav a.nav-account.active` but you need to write `nav a.nav-account:active`

Comment: for small viewports you need to edit `.navbar-default .navbar-toggle` style

Comment: I don't feel lucky, it works but for only 1 second, it does not stay with the specified colors! http://jsfiddle.net/jo6Lpyt7/

Comment: I wrote - When menu axpanded (**after click on buton**), you need define styles for `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a`   http://jsfiddle.net/t59pmLe5/

Answer (score 1):

Because instead `nav a.nav-account.active` you need to apply styles to `.nav .open > a` or `.nav .open .dropdown-toggle` will work:

```
.nav .open .dropdown-toggle {
   color: red !important;
   background: red !important;
   border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

[Jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/5o06orcg/2/)